# tomee - how to use RESOURCE_LOCAL datasource

Tags: jpa, jta, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I have some classes (ejb, webservices, mdb, etc..) that can use JTA. For some classes I need `RESOURCE_LOCAL` (can't be injected). However I can't get tomee to reference the jndi name of `RESOURCE_LOCAL`. How do you setup tomee and `RESOURCE_LOCAL`? I can't seem to find one good example online, I would prefer not to put any usernames and passwords in my `persistence.xml` file.

`tomee.xml` has this:

```
<Resource id="MYDS" type="DataSource">
         JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
         JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/maestro
         UserName myusername
         Password mypassword
         JtaManaged false
</Resource>
```

`persistence.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name = "MYDS" transaction-type = "RESOURCE_LOCAL">     
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>        
            <non-jta-data-source>MYDS</non-jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>        
</persistence>
```

I am using name `MYDS` in `EntityManagerFactory` lookup, but get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [MYDS]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    ... 36 more 
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [MYDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [MYDS].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:828)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
```

Comment: what version of TomEE is this?

Comment: 7.0.1 and 7.0.1 (latest 2 versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution seems to be this (still verifying):
(not very intuative or documented, adding openejb:Resource to JPA and JPA doesn't work, removing it from RESOURCE_LOCAL and RESOURCE_LOCAL doesn't work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name = "MYDS" transaction-type = "RESOURCE_LOCAL">     
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>        
            <non-jta-data-source>openejb:Resource/MYDS</non-jta-data-source>
  </persistence-unit>        
    <persistence-unit name="MYDSJPA" transaction-type = "JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>MYDS</jta-data-source>             
        </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

how do you get your persistence unit? Manually?

If using injection:

```
@PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory emf;
@PersistenceContect EntityManager em;
```

TomEE resolves the datasource for you from its short name (id in tomee.xml) otherwise you need to give it the full JNDI name which I think is java:openejb/Resource/MYDS

Comment: yes I am injecting the EnityManager, the issue seems to be different jndi naming schemes for JTA vs RESOURCE_LOCAL (from my answer above). I think this is new or a bug since old versions of tomee I remember using the same jndi type string

Comment: The JTA one should be provided by tomee where the non JTA one can likely be looked-up by hibernate depending the version and config even if tomee still provides it to the provider (hibernate ignores it it seems since it calls JndiServiceImpl).